# Finding K Highest Sums from multiple integer lists

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given several lists/array of integers ..need to find out the K highest sums picking only one element from each list.Each list/array contains integers in a non-increasing sequence.

For example, given the input:

```
[5,4,3,2,1]
[4,1]
[5,0,0]
[6,4,2]
[1]
```

and if the value of K is 5 i.e 5 highest sums.

The result will be :

```
[21,20,19,19,18]
```

example of the input method might look something like this :

```
List<Integer> fetchHighestSums(int[][] lists,int n){  }
```

Can somebody please help with java code for the above.

Comment: Does your teacher know we are doing your homework?

Comment: If you had a solution for the specific example above, and I gave you one more array of integers to pick an element from, how would you solve the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for someone else to write the code, and doesn't identify a specific question or problem.

Answer (score 2):

This has a simple greedy algorithm. Sort all the numbers into an array say P, labelling each number with information of the array the no. belongs to. 
Initially the sum would be the sum of all the highest(first) number from each array and lets store each of these no.s in another array S. We remove these numbers from P. Next step would be to replace one of these numbers from S with the next highest number from P. We pick the next highest from P and remove the corresponding no. from S and remove the selected no. from P. We do this till we get the k highest no.s or till P is empty.
For example, if

```
A = [5,4,3,2,1]
B = [4,1]
C = [5,0,0]
D = [6,4,2]
E = [1] 

P = D[0] A[0] C[0] A[1] B[0] D[1] A[2] D[2] A[3] D[2] A[4] B[1] E[0] C[2]
S = D[0] + A[0] + C[0] + B[0] + E[0] and P = A[1] D[1] A[2] D[2] A[3] D[2] A[4] B[1] C[2]
S = D[0] + A[1] + C[0] + B[0] + E[0] and P = D[1] A[2] D[2] A[3] D[2] A[4] B[1] C[2]
S = D[1] + A[0] + C[0] + B[0] + E[0] and P = A[2] D[2] A[3] D[2] A[4] B[1] C[2]
S = D[0] + A[2] + C[0] + B[0] + E[0] and P = D[2] A[3] D[2] A[4] B[1] C[2]
```

...etc

Answer (score 1):

first, by reading your function header, i think it's a 2D array, so the length of each list 
should be the same

```
List<Integer> fetchHighestSums(int[][] lists,int n){
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(lists==null || lists.length==0 || lists[0].length==0){
        return result;
    }
    else if(n>lists[0].length*lists.length){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        int[] indexes = new int[lists.length];
        int sum = 0;
        int curMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int curMaxIndex = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            sum = 0;
            curMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for(int j=0; j<lists.length; j++){
                sum += lists[j][indexes[j]];
                if(lists[j][indexes[j]]>curMax){
                    curMaxIndex = j;
                }
            }
            result.add(sum);
            indexes[curMaxIndex]++;
        }
    return result;
}
```

this is at most O(nm) time and needs O(m) space (m=#of columns and n=#of rows)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do this,although i'm not sure what you're learning in class that they expect you to apply. A few of the 'easier' solutions to me would be just make an array of every possible sum, taking one from each list... sort it and take the first (or last) N values. As long as you're not being graded on beauty.